# How do I obtain a value of an HTML field with C#/C++

Tags: c#, c++, html

I'm using HtmlElement to get an HTML element by it's ID and trying to display this value and return it (as a String).  The problem is that it sees it as an Object.

I have a webBrowser in the code with an HTML file that has:

```
<label id="Address" text="asdf"></label>
```

In my C++ header file I have

```
   HtmlElement^ element = this->webBrowser1->Document->GetElementById("Address");
String^ asdf = element->GetAttribute("text");
return asdf;
```

This builds, but when I launch the program, I get an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I can't use System::Convert.ToString(); either, it won't let me build with that.

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: C# or VC++?  The `->` operators aren't used in C# that I know of.

Comment: @Nathan: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h.aspx, although personally I'm still confused at what he's doing.

Comment: @Nathan: C++ sorry I messed up.  This is in a header file that is accessed through my C# program.

@Yuriy: Trying to access the value of an HTML Element in a webBrowser that's in my C# program.

Element is: <label id="Address" text="asdf"></label>

Through the C++ Header file I'm trying to get access to the text "asdf" that's in the label with the id of "Address"

Comment: Do you get the correct html if you do return this->webBrowser1->DocumentText  ?

Comment: @Jesper Palm: I tried that, and nothing happens.  I'm guessing nothing is returned.  Is it supposed to be a String?

Comment: @John: Yes is is supposed to be the source of your html file. So this means that your html file isn't loaded into the webControl. What does that code look like?

Comment: @Jesper Palm: This webControl1 loads an HTML file from a Resource which contains Google maps JS in it, a few invisible buttons and labels which I'm trying to "store values in it," and grabbing it through C#.  It shows up when i build and run the form, but for some reason not being recognized in the code.  I'm finally able to run the x64 debugger (some components weren't registered and required a repair), so I now know that the HtmlElement element line is the one returning the exception.  Element is null at that point.

Comment: @John: How is the HTML file loaded into the webBrowser control? With the DocumentText property or do you navigate to the actual file path? The problem seems to be that you are running the above code when the webBrowser control is in a state where nothing is loaded (yet?).

Comment: @Jesper: It navigates to the actual path.  When I debug it, the value of a string where I do DocumentText shows up, but not the whole HTML.  It dies out at around 4,000 characters.  I'm not sure if that's a display limit of the MVS or a limit of the data type?  I'm going to try the code elsewhere, I didn't think of it not being loaded yet.  Thanks for your continued help/explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally figured out the problem after switching projects and coming back to it after a while.

I forgot the 'System::Object^ sender' part in my header file.  Now all the HtmlElement stuff works.:

public: System::String^ GetAddress(System::Object^ sender)

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Which line throws the exception - the first one or the second one?

There are 4 or 5 places in that code which could throw that exception, and I would start by working out which one it is.

Comment: Sorry, this line throws the exception.

String^ asdf = element->GetAttribute("text");

Comment: @John H: Then your label isn't found and element is null.

Comment: @Jesper Palm: thanks, I had to add to check if it was null.  I guess it is, and it's not finding my label/element now... :(

Comment: John - Jesper's advice in a comment on your question is really good, and you should try that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "runat" attribute within your tag (note that I've changed the text's position):

```
<label id="Address" runat="server">asdf</label>
```

Then, in .cs code, you get the text using the text property of the object.

```
Response.Write(Address.Text);
```

The -> operator is not used for what you are trying to do. It is used combined with pointers. Check this documentation: [-> Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s8bz4d5h%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I think that he is using c++ and the WebBrowser control. Not ASP.NET

Comment: Hmm you're right, I've read "C#" on the title. I might be blind, now I see the C++ =/

Answer (score 0):

**This is under the assumption of using C#**

You should be able to grab ahold of the label in the code behind by adding the `runat="server"` attribute to the label (even if it's just a plain old HTML label).

On the back end, you will then be able to access it by:

```
this.Address.InnerText
```

InnerText is the proper way to get the text from an HTML label in C#, not a text attribute.  So instead of having this:

```
<label id="Address" text="asdf"></label> <!-- broke -->
```

use this with the codebehind I mentioned:

```
<label id="Address" runat="server">asdf</label> <!-- works great -->
```